# Trying to make some img buttons stay in a horizontal line in the middle but when I get them in the middle the stack vertical instead

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a horizontal line of img buttons stay in the middle no matter what size the window is but hen I get the buttons to stay on the middle they won't stay horizontal but instead stack in a vertical line

I've tried changing around the margin: to different numbers and code
I've also tried making the display:block a lot of other codes but this is the only one that centers them, but its also what is making stack instead of being in a line

html:

```
    <div id="topborder"></div>
    <div class="buttongroup">
        <img src="icon/home.png" class="button" width="5%">
        <img src="icon/about.png" class="button" width="5%">
        <img src="icon/podcast.png" class="button" width="5%">
    </div>
```

css:

```
.button{
    border:1px solid ;
    color: green;
    opacity: 0.7 ;
    transition: 0.3s ;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block; 

}
.buttongroup .button:hover {opacity: 1;}

.buttongroup {
    width:100vw;
}
```

I expect the img buttons to stay in a horizontal line in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block` in the **button** class. And also add `text-align:center` to make div center in your main class.

```css
.button {
    border: 1px solid;
    color: green;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.buttongroup .button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.buttongroup {
    width: 100vw;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="topborder"></div>
<div class="buttongroup">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="button" width="5%">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="button" width="5%">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="button" width="5%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to be certain that they will always be in a line, use flexbox:

```
.buttongroup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Also your transition won't work because it has no property that it should transtion.